# How to substitute variable in string directly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I remember having seen that direct substitution like the below should be possible:

```
py = 'Python'
print(f'Hello {py}')
```

With the purpose to get:

> Hello Python

But I can't make it work, or maybe I just use an Python 3 that is not new enough.

What is the syntax and what Python version supports direct substitution?

Comment: That's correct syntax. Requires python 3.6

Comment: I think you need python 3.6 for that. Else use `format`: `'Hello {py}'.format(py=py)`

Comment: Thanks; I am using Python ver. 3.5, so that explains it...